# How to get back indices and column labels after groupby and apply operations?

Tags: pandas, group-by

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.arange(0, 12).reshape(3, 4))
df.index = ["a", "b", "c"]
df.columns = [["d", "d", "e", "e"], ["f", "g", "f", "g"]]
df.columns.names = ["L1", "L2"]
df.groupby(level="L1", axis=1).apply(
    lambda x: scipy.stats.ttest_1samp(x, axis=1, popmean=0).pvalue
)
```

This returns:

```
L1
d    [0.49999999999999956, 0.07044657495455454, 0.0...
e    [0.12566591637800234, 0.0488745039443948, 0.03...
    dtype: object
```

since `scipy.stats.ttest_1samp` outputs an object with numpy arrays. But I would like to convert it back to a DataFrame with the correct indexes `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with Pandas `T` property:

```py
series = df.groupby(level="L1", axis=1).apply(
    lambda x: scipy.stats.ttest_1samp(x, axis=1, popmean=0).pvalue
)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(series.tolist(), index=series.index, columns=df.index).T
```

Then:

```py
L1         d         e
a   0.500000  0.125666
b   0.070447  0.048875
c   0.037405  0.030292
```